# How to get username/password/hostname/port/SID to establish connection in SQL developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed Oracle database 21c and sqldeveloper. During the installation of oracle database 21c I inputted my password upon the prompt. I tried to key in the password and the given username SYS to create connection in sqldeveloper but I got the error

> Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=9mv7VkLpQniPUhJwegf7OQ==)

I'm trying to create a local database to practice SQL and I'm not looking to connect to an external database. What should I do in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: try server: Localhost, port: 1521, and service: orcl - but i'm not sure what you named your database

Comment: At a command prompt, enter the command 'lsnrctl status'.  Examine the output and you should see the host, port, and a list of available 'services'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just do this instructions to connect to the database via sql developer:

1- Startup database (if you do not starttup database yet);

2- In OS prompt execute:

```
lsnrctl start
```

The command start your listener up.

3- In OS prompt execute (If you are using linux OS):

```
echo $ORACLE_SID
ifconfig
```

The first shows your database sid and the second shows your OS IP. The port is usually 1521.

4- In sql developer inter connection name for example Oracle_conn, username and password and set role for the user.

Then you should enter Ip,Port and Sid you obtained in step 4.

5- Press Test or Connect and Enjoy!
[image]